# GoogleAppEngineLauncher not found after installing Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-app-engine

After installing the Google Cloud Platform SDK (for 64-bit windows), I get a failure because there is no GoogleAppEngineLauncher.exe installed ... indeed there is no "launcher" folder at all (where the GoogleAppEngineLauncher.exe lives).

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the SDK several times .. with no indicated errors, until attempting to run the Google App Engine launcher.

(Windows 7 Ultimate is OS)

Comment: I just tried a fresh Google Cloud SDK (https://cloud.google.com/sdk) install and it installed the Launcher by default and created a desktop shortcut for it. Does it not do this for you? If you have the Cloud SDK Shell but not the Launcher, open the Shell, then run the command `gcloud components list`. Does it say that the gae-python-launcher-win component is "Installed"?

Comment: Also possibly useful to know: `gcloud info` will print version numbers of the various components. My fresh install is Google Cloud SDK 0.9.67, with app-engine-python and gae-python-launcher-win version 1.9.23.

Answer (score -1):

From Source given in the link: 
http://www-personal.umich.edu/~csev/books/gae/handouts/AppEngine-Install-Windows.pdf

Your Launcher might be in this directory.
   ***C:\Documents and Settings(yourusername)\Local Settings\Temp.***
 If not,Consult the Above manual for proper Installation.

Comment: I appreciate your attempt .. but this information relates to an old version of  Windows and an earlier version of GAI sdk).  I cannot find a launcher in the analog of this location on my Windows 7 system

Comment: @ErstwhileIII  Have a Look at this once again.  [link](From http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/devenvironment.html) . If you are using the Zip archive version of the SDK, you will find these commands in the google_appengine directory.